# C3 graph overlapping x-axis label

Tags: javascript, c3.js

C3 graph overlap x-axis labels which is in date time format. I have googled this query but didn't get any solution for it.Is it possible that c3 only shows couple of date time rather then showing altogether which result in overlap x-axis labels [image]

```
var data = {
    x: 'x',
    xFormat:'%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M',
    empty: {
        label: {
          text: "No Data"
        }
    },
    columns: [
        ['x', '{$dateArray}'],
        ['Attack', {$data}],
    ],colors: {
        Attack: '#67b7dc',
    },
    types: {
        Attack: 'area'
    }};
var chart = c3.generate({bindto: '#chart1',
size: {
    height: 630,
},
data: data,
grid: {
    x: {
        show: true
    },
    y: {
        show: true
    }
},
tooltip: {
    format: {
        value: function (value, ratio, id) {
            var format = value+' Gbps  [ IP: '+destIp[value]+' ]';
            return format;            
        }
    }
},
zoom: {
    enabled: true
},
subchart: {
    show: true
},axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'timeseries',
        tick: {
            format: '%b %d, %H:%M',
            rotate: 90,
            multiline: false
        }
    },
    y: {
        tick: {
            format: function (d) {
                return d.toFixed(3);
            }
        },
        label: {
            text: 'Attack Size ( Gbps )',
            position: 'outer-middle'
        }
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use c3.js chart config tick.count, set it to desired integer value like 2,3 or 4.

Use [c3.js Timeseries Chart exmaple](http://c3js.org/samples/axes_x_tick_count.html) to play with this config.

**Problem without tick.count:-**
[image]

**Problem solved with tick.count config:-**
[image]